# MUI themes in styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#262C27',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff0000',
    },
  }
});

export default theme;
```

I have these themes and i would like to use them in a Styled MUI component

```
import theme from '../Themes/Constant';

export const ButtonText = styled(Button)(() => ({
  color: 'white',
  display: 'block',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  borderRadius:'0',
  margin:'1vw'
}));
export const ButtonSignUp = styled(ButtonText)(() => ({
  /*background: theme.secondary.main,*/
}));
```

But when i do this assignment it dosent render, On the other hand, when inside a component without styling them it works perfect.
`<AppBar position='static' sx={{boxShadow:'0', bgcolor:'primary.main'}}>`
Any clue why is happening and what to do to solve it?

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, sugiero traducir la pregunta a Español, estas en Stack Overflow en Español